# Python Split a column that has both metric and imperial units

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, units-of-measurement

I have a column that has a mixture of units and I need to break that into two different columns: One for metric (mm, cm, m) and one for Imperial (in, ft, yd)

```
d = {'col1': [1 in, 2 mm, 3 ft, 4 yd, 5 m, 6cm]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Split that into:

```
Index    df_metric  df_imperial
 0    |            |      1 in
---------------------------------
 1    |     2 mm   |
---------------------------------
 2    |            |     3 ft
---------------------------------
 3    |            |     4 yd
---------------------------------
 4    |     5 m    |
---------------------------------
 5    |     6 cm   |
```

I have tried:

```
def seperate_units(df, col, numbers):
    if numbers.find('yd') > -1 or numbers.find('in') > -1 or numbers.find('ft') > -1 or numbers.find('"') > -1:
        print(numbers)
        df[col+'_imperial'].append(numbers)
    else:
        df[col+'_imperial'].append('')
    return df[col+'_imperial']
```

But I cannot get that to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try pandas [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```py
d = {'col1': ['1 in', '2 mm', '3 ft', '4 yd', '5 m', '6cm']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['metric'] = df[df['col1'].str.contains(r'mm|cm|m')]['col1']
df['imperial'] = df[df['col1'].str.contains(r'in|ft|yd')]['col1']

print(df)


#    col1 metric imperial
# 0  1 in    NaN     1 in
# 1  2 mm   2 mm      NaN
# 2  3 ft    NaN     3 ft
# 3  4 yd    NaN     4 yd
# 4   5 m    5 m      NaN
# 5   6cm    6cm      NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1 in', '2 mm', '3 ft', '4 yd', '5 m', '6cm']})
```

You can us a regex to find metric units and split on this condition:

```
metric = df.col1.str.match('\d+\s*[cm]?m')

pd.concat([df.where(metric, '').add_suffix('_metric'),
           df.where(~metric, '').add_suffix('_imperial')],
          axis=1)
```

Here the regex matches a number followed with cm/m/mm, you can update it based on your real use case.
In the `where`, I replaced with empty string `''`, but you can remove this to have NaN, or replace it with anything else if you prefer.

output:

```
  col1_metric col1_imperial
0                      1 in
1        2 mm              
2                      3 ft
3                      4 yd
4         5 m              
5         6cm
```

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
m=df['col1'].str.contains(r'mm|cm|m')
#checking for metric
y=df['col1'].str.contains(r'in|ft|yd')
#checking for imperial
```

Finally:

```
df.loc[:,'df_metric']=df.loc[m,'col1']
df.loc[:,'df_imperial']=df.loc[y,'col1']
#If needed:
#df[['df_metric','df_imperial']]=df[['df_metric','df_imperial']].fillna('')
```

Now you print `df` you will get your expected output